# Limit of $xf(x)$ where $f$ is a decreasing integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Looking for a little help on getting started with this problem.

Let $f: (0, \infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ be a decreasing function which is integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure restricted to $(0, \infty)$.

Show that $xf(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $f$ is decreasing, for every $x>0$,
$$xf(2x)\le\int_x^{2x} f(t)dt\le xf(x).$$
Since $f$ is integrable, 
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\int_x^{2x} f(t)dt=0.$$
The conclusion follows, where $f$ is not necessarily to be positive.

Comment: Where does the first inequality come from?

Comment: @dinky: Because $f$ is decreasing, $f(2x)\le f(t)\le f(x)$ when $t\in[x,2x]$. Integrating them over $[x,2x]$, then the first inequality follows.